# Update chart axis labels after hover - chart.js

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, axis-labels

I'm working with chart.js version 3.7.1. I want to replace y axis labels after hovering it. Hover event works fine and it recognizes y axis quite good but labels don't replace. I tried using `update()` method from Chart API but it didn't help.

I also prepared some quick playground where I placed a custom chart with this problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x3sncg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine your `afterEvent` plugin with a [`ticks.callback`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) function as shown below:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    y: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      ticks: {
        callback: value => value + (this.isHoveringYAxe ? '$' : '')
      }
    }
  }
},
plugins: [{
  id: 'customHover',
  afterEvent: (chart, args) => {
    const event = args.event;
    if (event.type == 'mousemove') {
      if (event.x < chart.scales.y.width && !this.isHoveringYAxe) {
        this.isHoveringYAxe = true;
        chart.update();
      } else if (event.x >= chart.scales.y.width && this.isHoveringYAxe) {
        this.isHoveringYAxe = false;
        chart.update();
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Please take a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-change-y-ticks-on-hover?file=src/app/app.component.ts) and see how it works.